# How to export List/Collection of data tables to csv in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, export-to-csv

I am getting list of data tables returned by Web API call and I want that list of data tables to be exported to csv file using AngularJS where each sheet in csv contains data for each table in list of data tables.
It should happen on a button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV does not support multiple sheets concept. You can create multiple CSV files for each table. Here is a directive for the same. http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-csv

If you want to export in same sheet, you might want to do it on server side "export to excel". In case of Java, Apache POI is a good option to use. https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will pursue the approach of creating excel at server side.